# Value binding on span not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

For some reason, I can't return the value of the `idUser` binding:

HTML:

```html
<span data-bind="value: idUser">1</span>
```

At the end of HTML:

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        startJs();
    }); 
</script>
```

JS File:

```
function startJs() {
    var vm = new vmUser();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
}

var vmUser = function () {
    self = this;
    self.idUser = ko.observable();
}
```

When I try to use `self.idUser();` the value is always undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Points to notice :**

- you aren't assigning any value to observable so by default it takes `undefined`
- span tag takes `text` not `value` as it is not editable

**Text binding**

> The text binding causes the associated DOM element to display the text
>   value of your parameter.
>
> Typically this is useful with elements like < span> or < em> that
>   traditionally display text, but technically you can use it with any
>   element.

Documentation **[here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html)** .

sample fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/26806/)** to check output .

*Note :* May be a possible misconception by seeing the view `<span data-bind="value: idUser">1</span>` having `1` b/w span tags you may be expecting `1` to be displayed/assigned but it is other way around in ko. As you have `data-bind` on html tag i.e span(any) which will replace any inner content with binded observable value i.e `undefined` in your case

Comment: Damnit super cool, stop answering all my Knockoutjs questions... Too bad like all of your answers arn't getting marked as correct..